# Model not binding in array of an object in v-for in vueJs2

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I have a model named as `selected_category` in this model is a array named `chosen_features` and in this array is an array named as `selected_conditions` ,

So when I loop `chosen_features` to modify the `selected_conditions` in each chosen_feature model binding in select input not working! Something like this in code:

```html
<div v-for="chosen_feature in selected_category.chosen_features">

   <div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

         <div class="card card-default">
          <div class="card-header"> @{{ chosen_feature.label }}

   </div>
    <div class="card-block">

      <div class="col-md-9">
       <select v-model="chosen_feature.selected_conditions" multiple="multiple">
<option v-for="condition in chosen_feature.conditions" :value="condition.value">@{{condition.label}}</option>

     </select>
```

In this case model of `chosen_feature.selected_conditions` by v-model not updating! But in vue developer inspector for chrome it has been updated but in dom! not anything!

EDITED!

Js code too:

```
 new Vue({
    el     : '#myapp',
    data   : {
        type               : 'none',
        category           : {
            count     : '{{ $categories->count() }}',
            error     : false,
            selected  : 0,
            validation: false,
            show      : true,

        },
        event              : {
            count     : '{{ $events->count() }}',
            error     : false,
            selected  : 0,
            validation: false,
            show      : true,

        },
        error              : false,
        discount           : false,
        coordinates        : [],
        slides             : [],
        categories         : {!! $categories->toJson() !!},
        features           : {!! $features->toJson() !!},
        selected_features  : [],
        selected_categories: [],


    },
    mounted: function () {

        this.features.map(function (value, key) {
            Object.assign(value, {
                color              : 'dark',
                selected_conditions: [],


            })
        });

        this.categories.map(function (value, key) {
            Object.assign(value, {
                color          : 'dark',
                chosen_features: [],


            })
        });


    },
    updated: function () {

        switch (this.type) {
            case('category'):
                this.event.error = false;

                if (this.category.count < 1) {
                    this.category.error = true;
                    this.error          = true;

                } else {
                    this.error = false;


                }
                break;
            case('event'):
                this.category.error = false;

                if (this.event.count < 1) {
                    this.event.error = true;
                    this.error       = true;


                }
                else {
                    this.error = false;

                }


                break;
        }

    },


    methods: {

        addCoordinate: function () {

            if (this.coordinates.length === 0) {
                this.coordinates.push({
                    id: this.coordinates.length + 1,

                })

            } else {
                this.coordinates.push({
                    id: this.coordinates[this.coordinates.length - 1].id + 1,

                })
            }


        },


        removeCoordinate: function (coordinate) {
            this.coordinates.splice(this.coordinates.indexOf(coordinate), 1)
        },


        addSlide: function () {

            if (this.slides.length === 0) {
                this.slides.push({
                    id        : this.slides.length + 1,
                    show_image: false,

                })


            } else {
                this.slides.push({
                    id        : this.slides[this.slides.length - 1].id + 1,
                    show_image: false,

                })
            }


        },


        removeSlide: function (slide) {
            this.slides.splice(this.slides.indexOf(slide), 1)
        },

        readURL: function (slide) {
            console.log(slide);
            var input = $('#slide-' + slide.id)[0]
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    slide.show_image = true;

                    $('#slide-image-' + slide.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        },

        addFeature: function (feature) {
            data = {
                id                 : feature.id,
                label              : feature.label,
                title              : feature.title,
                description        : feature.description,
                conditions         : feature.conditions,
                selected_conditions: [],
            }
            if (this.selected_features.length > 0) {

                if (search(data.id, this.selected_features) === undefined) {
                    this.selected_features.push(data)
                    Object.assign(feature, {
                        color: 'success',

                    })

                } else {
                    Object.assign(search(feature.id, this.features), {
                        color: 'dark',

                    })

                    this.selected_features.splice(this.selected_features.indexOf(feature), 1)
                }

            } else {
                this.selected_features.push(data)
                Object.assign(feature, {
                    color: 'success',

                })

            }


        },

        removeFeature: function (feature) {
            Object.assign(search(feature.id, this.features), {
                color: 'dark',

            })

            this.selected_features.splice(this.selected_features.indexOf(feature), 1)

        },

        addCategory: function (category) {
            data = {
                id             : category.id,
                title          : category.title,
                description    : category.description,
                chosen_features: [],
            }
            if (this.selected_categories.length > 0) {

                if (search(data.id, this.selected_categories) === undefined) {
                    this.selected_categories.push(data)
                    Object.assign(category, {
                        color: 'success',

                    })

                } else {
                    Object.assign(search(category.id, this.categories), {
                        color: 'dark',

                    })

                    this.selected_categories.splice(this.selected_categories.indexOf(category), 1)
                }

            } else {
                this.selected_categories.push(data)
                Object.assign(category, {
                    color: 'success',

                })

            }


        },

        removeCategory: function (category) {
            Object.assign(search(category.id, this.categories), {
                color: 'dark',

            })

            this.selected_categories.splice(this.selected_categories.indexOf(category), 1)

        },

        addConditionToChosenFeature: function (condition, feature, category) {
            search(feature.id, category.chosen_features).selected_conditions.push(condition)
            console.log(search(feature.id, category.chosen_features).selected_conditions);
        },

        Discounting: function () {
            console.log('Changed')
            if ($('#discount-button').is(":checked")) {
                this.discount = true


            } else {
                this.discount = false
            }
        },

        Searching: function (nameKey, myArray) {
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                if (myArray[i].id === parseInt(nameKey)) {
                    return myArray[i];
                }
            }
        }
    },


});
```

Comment: How do you set the value `chosen_feature.selected_conditions`

Comment: Post the JavaScript portion too.

Comment: @milo526 I mention it, i set it by v-model in select